# Parse xml stored in BLOB with postgresql

Tags: blob

I'm working on a new project where I'm supposed to use blob hashes stored in a postgresql database to access xml files online, parse the xml files from my web browser, and populate postgresql database tables with appropriate fields.

This needs to be an automated process that runs every hour or two hours, so speed is really important

I've done something similar in the past where the xml was simply stored in the postgresql database.

I was just wondering the best practices are for connecting to a blob and parsing xml from an online browser most efficiently.

Currently, I'm only familiar with Python and postgresql. Is this doable using those packages? It seems from rudimentary research that Java is the language of choice when dealing with blobs. But it would make my life easier if I could stick to my core competencies.

I'd appreciate any advice/help on best practices and methods.

Thanks!